# CI Model is not loading proberly?

Tags: php, mysql

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->load->helper('login');
    $this->load->model('profile_model');
    $this->load->model('common_model');
}
function index()
{
    $this->user_information();
}
function user_information()
{
    if($this->input->post('submit'))
    {

    }
    else
    {
    $data['settings']=$this->common_model->get_user_settings();
    $this->load->view('profile/user-settings',$data);
    }
}
```

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Settings::$common_model

Filename: controllers/settings.php

Line Number: 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function get_user_settings() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\dandalo\application\controllers\settings.php on line 24
```

This is my code. I am getting this error. I dont know how come this kind of error when I load the model correctly.

Model Code:

```
<?php
class common_model extends CI_Model
{
    public $datet;
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        //$this->load->model('buy_model');
        $this->datet=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    function get_user_settings()
    {
        $this->db->select('user_name,u_first_name,u_last_name,u_email,u_profile_image,fb_id');
        $this->db->where('user_id',user_id());
        return $this->db->get('en_user')->result();
    }}?>
```

This is my model code. I also extended the CI_model. still I am getting error.

Comment: Can you show the code for model ?

Comment: did you extend CI_Model ?

Comment: change to class CommonModel extends CI_Model

Comment: @Vivek please show your model code again

Comment: look at my answer. have you tried according my answer

Comment: also try to make public function get_user_settings()

Comment: I have tried everything you said... but no one works

Comment: show your controller class or full code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

locate your model in **application/models**

```
profile_model.php
common_model.php
```

your model class looks like

```
class ProfileModel extends CI_Model
class CommonModel extends CI_Model
```

load in controller

```
$this->load->model('profile');
$this->load->model('common');
```

then call model function

```
$data['settings']=$this->common->get_user_settings();
```

For more :- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: Hi Dude... Model is being loaded... But When I call the function, It is getting error...

Comment: make function public function

Comment: Hi Dude found that issue... The problem was in profile model.. So only common model was not loaded... Thank you for your support...

Answer (score 0):

Your model class name should be Start with first latter uppercase, It should be

```
class Common_model extends CI_Model
OR
class Common_Model extends CI_Model
```

Instead of

```
class common_model extends CI_Model
```

> Where Model_name is the name of your class. Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

take a look on http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html#anatomy